# TeXworks and textedit:// links

Tags: texworks, forward-inverse-search, lilypond

I use TeXworks for typesetting LilyPond music. The syntax is very similar, and the idea as well (text file -> PDF), so it's very convenient.

However, LilyPond doesn't (obviously) use syncTeX for inverse-search, it uses the `textedit://` links. I would like to configure these links to work for forward-inverse search.

I see two possibilities:

- Make TeXworks recognize `textedit://` links.
- Manage to exctract the `textedit://` links and convert them into syncTeX.

I'm insterested in partial solutions as well, once a specific idea is proposed, I can implement it myself if it's a reasonable idea.

Comment: Interesting point, but isn't this essentially a feature request for TeXworks?

Comment: @JosephWright I'm not 100% sure about it. I checked the syntax of syncTeX, and if one is given the list of all textedit commands in the PDF file, it should be possible to create a face syncTeX file. This would be possible in a seperate script. I'll clarify it a bit more.

Comment: I think this should be moved to a TeXworks feature request. An answer here would just be an implementation of that feature request.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Lilypond Documentation](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/configuring-the-system-for-point-and-click), it is possible to configure what application opens when you click on a `textedit://` link by placing setting up the environment variable `LYEDITOR` with the command to open the application of your choice.

I don't have any experience with TeXWorks, but it looks like you have a `--position=` option that would allow you to open setup lilypond to open at the correct line, at least.